# Remote-SSH through Visual Studio Code not working because of permissions through WSL cross referencing

Tags: ssh, security, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I have set up a linux server and I set the server to only accept ssh with an rsa pub key file. SSHing through the WSL client works but using Remote-SSH on VSC is not working. I get the error message:

Could not establish connection to "IP": The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

When I looked at the output on VSC, I got:

```
[13:05:57.029] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:05:57.222] > @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:05:57.222] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[13:05:57.238] > @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> Permissions for '\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\ryanp\\.ssh\\id_rsa' are too open.
> It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.   
> This private key will be ignored.
> Load key "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\ryanp\\.ssh\\id_rsa": bad permissions    
> swingology@192.168.1.20: Permission denied (publickey).
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

I tried to edit the permissions of the id_rsa file through explorer.exe . at the directory of the rsa pub file, but I couldn't find the security tab in its properties. Even after forcing the security tab to show through gpedit.msc and regedit. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH is extremely particular about the permissions of key files and will simply refuse to work if they're not correct.  As a result, you're going to find that trying to use the Windows SSH with a Linux key file or a Linux SSH with a key file is going to be difficult, if not impossible, since each OS's OpenSSH is not designed to read the permissions of the other OS properly.

You're probably going to want to copy the `id_rsa` file from the WSL environment into your Windows home directory if you want to use the Windows OpenSSH.